# Unity - Resources.LoadAll Doesnt Load Anything

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
GameObject[] Stats;
```

Then

```
GameObject[] Stats = Resources.LoadAll("Stats") as GameObject[];
```

And Last

```
Instantiate (Stats[Random.Range(0, Stats.Length)], spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
```

iam using this to spawn a random Stat at a spawn point I got all the Stats in the Stat folder which is in the resources folder I don't know what's wrong

Comment: try using  Resources.LoadAll("Stat") as GameObject[] ;

Comment: well, that what iam using ! look again at the question @SouravSachdeva

Comment: No , i was saying the folder name is Stat right not Stats

Comment: No Its Stats iam pretty sure @SouravSachdeva

Comment: are you sure there is nothing at that spawnPos. can you show the complete code?

Comment: There's. The Error Is Array Index is Out of Range That Means That I Have a Number More Then The Length Which Is Impossible Because I put 0, stats.length Or the Array Is Empty And The Array Is Empty Because The LoadAll Didnt Work

Comment: Try Stats.Length -1

Comment: Still Not Working I Tried Everything Casting it Diffrent Ways And Everything Still Not Working ;( @SouravSachdeva

Comment: Do you still get the array index out of range ,if you do  try explicitly giving the size of the array. and show complete code please if you can ?

Comment: Its too Long But When I Try To Debug the length It Says 0 Which Is Cleared Array

Comment: Try fetching it as general Objects array and than enquire the length of stats than we can try casting it later . That's all i can think of  .

Comment: Thanks That Did Work But Instead Of Casting it Again To GameObject Which Didnt Work I just Instantiate it as Object Not GameObject I think u Should But That As An Answer Thanks bro @SouravSachdeva

Comment: And I Didnt Put The Files In The Resources Folder Which Was Another Problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had 2 problems the first was the folder was in Assets/Stats not in Assets/Resources/Stats,
And 2nd problem was casting the object To a gameobject wasn't working so i just instantiated a object and that did work!